# Auto-Hide Tab-Bar and Address-Bar in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, automation, fullscreen

Will maybe be marked as duplicate - however the question seems relevant since i haven't found any satisfying answers yet:

I use Chromium on Linux everyday and so far i'm enjoying the overall experience. But i'm mostly working from a 12.5" Laptop and would be saving about 10% of screen estate if hiding the Address- and Title-Bar would be possible.
Of course i know about the Full-Screen-Mode that i can access via the F11-Key but that is not what i want.
I'm looking for Chromium to Auto-Hide the Tab- and Address-Bar whenever my Chromium-Window is filling the entire screen (whenever it's maximized).

Since other Web-Browsers are supporting this feature and Chrome has supported it some time ago (i believe), i wonder if there is currently an option to achieve Auto-Hiding.
I would also go with a hack if somebody can come up with a solution that doesn't take ages to achieve.

If there is no option to do so - Can somebody tell me why? Does anybody have insights on why Google wouldn't support such a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "about:flags" the flag is no longer present, so likely the capability to hide the bar has been removed.